# Difference of independent random variables that is not unimodal

Tags: distributions, gaussian-mixture-distribution, mixture-distribution, iid

[This paywalled article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02056921) shows that the difference of two i.i.d. random variables is unimodal and symmetric if the distribution of the random variables is unimodal. Is there a non-unimodal distribution such that the difference isn't unimodal?

Comment: Non unimodal difference when RV is non unimodal itself is pretty easy. May you be asking for unimodal difference when RV is non unimodal instead?

Comment: @gunes No the first thing you mentioned (the 'easy' one) is what I was after. But when you described it as easy, I realized it was (eg bimodal betas distributions do the trick).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example of non-unimodal distribution where the distribution of difference is unimodal**:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be observations of a normal mixture distribution with expectations 0 and 3, standard deviations 1, and mixture proportions 0.5, 0.5. Below is a histogram of the difference distribution based on 10000 samples. It surprised me that it is unimodal

[image: Histogram of difference distribution]

**Example of non-unimodal distribution where the difference distribution is not unimodal**:

As above, the only difference is expectations 0 and 5:

[image: Histogram of difference distribution]